# SSL error in VMWare ESXi 5.5 when trying to add Host to VCenter

Tags: ssl, vmware-esxi

Recently I installed a new VMWare EsXi 5.5 Server in an ASUS Server with 32GB of RAM, I have a couple of tplink additional NICs and had to add the drivers from VMWARE bundle to original ISO and rebuil it following the process described in https://tinkertry.com/install-esxi-5-5-with-realtek-8111-or-8168-nic . After INstall all went OK and the server had access to the tplink NICs but when tried to add this new host to my existing VCenter this error appears in vpxd.log in VCenter

---

2016-03-28T13:40:54.680-04:00 [03192 info 'commonvpxLro' opID=1EF3038B-0000013B-3e] [VpxLRO] -- BEGIN task-internal-5373 -- datacenter-7 -- vim.Datacenter.queryConnectionI\
nfo -- e2151146-896a-380a-114d-a7aaf2406c7e(523d4e3b-cbcc-d7ac-2ced-865af33c3db7)

2016-03-28T13:40:54.684-04:00 [05492 error 'HttpConnectionPool-000001'] [ConnectComplete] Connect failed to ; cnx: (null), e\
rror: class Vmacore::Ssl::SSLException(SSL Exception: error:140000DB:SSL routines:SSL routines:short read)

2016-03-28T13:40:54.684-04:00 [03192 error 'httphttpUtil' opID=1EF3038B-0000013B-3e] [HttpUtil::ExecuteRequest] Error in sending request - SSL Exception: error:140000DB:SS\
L routines:SSL routines:short read

2016-03-28T13:40:54.684-04:00 [03192 error 'vpxdvpxdHostAccess' opID=1EF3038B-0000013B-3e] [VpxdHostAccess::Connect] Failed to discover version: vim.fault.HttpFault

2016-03-28T13:40:54.685-04:00 [03192 info 'commonvpxLro' opID=1EF3038B-0000013B-3e] [VpxLRO] -- FINISH task-internal-5373 -- datacenter-7 -- vim.Datacenter.queryConnection\
Info --

2016-03-28T13:40:54.685-04:00 [03192 info 'Default' opID=1EF3038B-0000013B-3e] [VpxLRO] -- ERROR task-internal-5373 -- datacenter-7 -- vim.Datacenter.queryConnectionInfo: \
vim.fault.NoHost:

--> Result:
--> (vim.fault.NoHost) {
-->    dynamicType = ,
-->    faultCause = (vmodl.MethodFault) null,
-->    name = "172.19.160.192",
-->    msg = "",
--> }
--> Args:
-->

---

Thanks in Advance for any help anyone could give me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuming the problem is Solved by installing the drivers into the original VMWAre ISO

[Eddyraz Blog](http://eddyraz-en.blogspot.com/2016/03/vmware-esxi-problems-with-not-suported.html)

Answer (score -1):

5.5 Update 3b disables SSLv3. Is it possible that your vCenter is older but you downloaded the newer ISO to install your new host? Make sure your vCenter server is updated to 3b before updating hosts or adding new 3b hosts.

This is the explanation from the VMware download site:

"Support for SSLv3 protocol is disabled by default
Note: In your vSphere environment, you need to update vCenter Server to vCenter Server 5.5 Update 3b before updating ESXi to ESXi 5.5 Update 3b. vCenter Server will not be able to manage ESXi 5.5 Update 3b, if you update ESXi before updating vCenter Server to version 5.5 Update 3b. For more information about the sequence in which vSphere environments need to be updated, refer KB 2057795.

VMware does not recommend re-enabling SSLv3 due to POODLE vulnerability.
Note: If at all you need to enable SSLv3, you need to enable the SSLv3 protocol for all components. For more information, refer KB 2139396.

VMware highly recommends you to update ESXi hosts to ESXi 5.5 Update 3b while managing them from vCenter Server 5.5 Update 3b."

Comment: Tanks a Lot , I had read that already, but as the article recommends I did not want to make the server vulnerable to POODLE , So What I did was to reread the blogpost and \
instead of making a new iso with the drivers included I opted for the option of After installing with the original old ISO and to succesfully added the host  to my VCenter\
 Server then include the vibs of the driver with the escli tool from the commandline in the ESXi and then reboot, I described the process in my blog: http://eddyraz-en.blogspot.com/2016/03/vmware-esxi-problems-with-not-suported.html